# What is the term for this piece of hardware?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

This is a silly question but what is the "official" term for what is carrying this hard drive?

I need to know if I can purchase it separately from the hard drive.

[image]

Comment: It's called a carrier, sled or tray.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is known as a hot-plug "drive carrier" or sometimes "drive sled", "tray" or "caddy"...

And yes, they can be purchased separately from the drive. There are companies [that specialize in providing aftermarket or replacement drive caddies](http://www.scsi4me.com/drive-caddies-trays.html). Ebay is also a popular source.

What type of server or enclosure is that carrier from?

Comment: I'd also go for "hard disk caddy".

Comment: @ewwhite it's for a Unitrends Recovery Archive "server".  The drive is just a 3TB Seagate.  I need a few more and Unitrends charges a premium, want to see if I can cobble it together myself but I can't find anything comparable.  The sled has activity indicator lights on the front.

Comment: @Tom Chances are that the carrier is just a [generic Supermicro drive tray](http://www.servethehome.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Supermicro-SC842TQ-665B-Drive-Caddy-View.jpg). They're ready available.

Comment: Yeah, here is an exact match to the sled I need, now if I could only find somewhere online to buy them...came up blank at Supermicro's site, sending an email: http://www.serversdirect.com/Image%20Library/Navigation%20Category/Landing%20Pages/1UProLand2.jpg

Comment: See if you can find a part number on the tray, that's the easiest to find some in stock. [Based off this page from Supermicro](http://www.techloops.com/supermicro-mcp220000430n-25-hdd-tray-hot-swap.html), you may even be able to find one that is similar but compatible with your chassis if you know that as well.

Comment: [This link seems to be the exact same thing](http://www.avadirect.com/product_details_parts.asp?PRID=17861). Plug "SUPERMICRO 05-01-815105-XXA" into ebay and you're good to go.

Comment: Oh _hard drive candy!!! /drool_ :)